# Save/Restore GroupResult with Celery in Django: None returned

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to save and restore GroupResult object after running task in Celery. The group result ID is returned and saved as expected. When I am trying to restore GroupResult with it:

```
from project.celery import app 

print(smstask.celery_result_id)
print(app.GroupResult.restore(smstask.celery_result_id))
```

I get (as example):

```
4780fc17-44d8-478f-a41a-e4333aaa03d4
None
```

For the Celery backend I am using Djcelery. Can it be the cause of the problem? 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

What else can you recommend to try? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should `save()` `GroupResult` if you have plan to use it later.
Then you can restore it by providing GroupResult.id to [`restore()`](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.GroupResult.restore) method:

```
from celery import group, result
from app.tasks import foo, bar

group_result = group([foo.s(), bar.s()])()
group_result.save()

restored_group_result = result.GroupResult.restore(group_result.id)
print(restored_group_result)
```